# How to add prefix to button text field

Tags: 8

I am trying to wrap button value with span as follows in my form alter hook.

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = '<span>'.t('Submit').'</span>';//Here want to add span        
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('green-gradient-button'));
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put html in there for the value. The value is used on the html submit button **value=""** e.g.:

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Submit" class="button js-form-submit form-submit">
```

What are you hoping to achieve by putting a span around the button? You could use #prefix #suffix to add the span

```
 '#prefix' => '<span>',
 '#suffix' => '</span>'
```

Or a custom template, this link might set you on the right track https://www.axelerant.com/resources/team-blog/playing-with-input-templates-in-drupal-8